# variable 'std::ofstream outfile' has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I already made a `CPP` program about this that creates  a lot of files with *Dev C++*, this one's with Dev C++ too but now it shows error. My `code` is specialized on creating `HTML` templates, but it shows `error`.

This is some of my `code` :

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::ofstream;
using std::endl;

void HelloWorld() {
    ofstream outfile ("html1.html");

    outfile << "<html> " << endl;
    outfile << "   <head> <title> Template Hello World </title> </head>" << endl;
    outfile << "   <body> <h1> Hello World! </h1> </body> " << endl;
    outfile << "</html> " << endl;
    outfile << "// Template HTML 2018 " << endl;
    cout << "Created Succesfuly! Directory: Program's folder " << endl;


    outfile.close(); 
}
```

Comment: you forgot to include ostream or ofstream or wtv

Comment: Try `#include <fstream>`.

Comment: Thanks to both. That worked. I'm beginner in C++ so

Comment: @SpanishMapping If you are a beginner, you should learn from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of coding randomly.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Who said it was random?

Comment: I'll do so. I just got in by using the templates, and some vids.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `#include <fstream>` to your includes :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::ofstream;
using std::endl;

void HelloWorld() {
    ofstream outfile ("html1.html");

    outfile << "<html> " << endl;
    outfile << "   <head> <title> Template Hello World </title> </head>" << endl;
    outfile << "   <body> <h1> Hello World! </h1> </body> " << endl;
    outfile << "</html> " << endl;
    outfile << "// Template HTML 2018 " << endl;
    cout << "Created Succesfuly! Directory: Program's folder " << endl;

    outfile.close();
}

int main()
{
    HelloWorld();
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Created Successfully! Directory: Program's folder
```